# Confusion regarding Hossein Pishro-Nik's definition of the CDF for discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is from his [online textbook](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_3_2_delta_function.php). Here is the function he uses to describe the CDF of a discrete random variable using the step function $u$

[image: Function]

Shouldn't this be $F_x(x) = \sum\limits_{x_k \in R_x} P_X(x_k)u(-(x - x_k))$ instead? That way we have that the probability of any event $x_k$ occuring beyond $x$ is $0$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is stated in the book is correct.The sum is over $k$ such that $x_k \leq x$ which means $x-x_k \geq 0$ (or $u(x-x_k)=1$).

You can take the example $X=1$ to see you get $F(0)=1$ according to your formula. This is clearly not correct.